# How do I efficiently extract image patches at specified locations?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to extract image patches of size `s x s x 3`  around specified 2D locations from an image (3 channels).

How can I do this efficiently without a `for` loop?  I know I can extract one patch around `(x,y)` location as:

```
apatch = I(y-s/2:y+s/2, x-s/2:x+s/2, :)
```

How can I do this for many patches?  I know I can use MATLAB's function `blockproc` but I can't specify the locations.

Comment: Do you have the (x,y) positions stored in a vector?

Comment: yes. I have (x,y) as a vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) from the image processing toolbox to transform each pixel neighbourhood into a **single column**.  The pixel neighbourhoods are selected such that each block is chose on a **column-basis**, which means that the blocks are constructed by traversing down the rows first, then proceeding to the next column and getting the neighbourhoods there.

You call [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) this way:

```
B = im2col(A, [M N]);
```

I'm assuming you'll want sliding / overlapping neighbourhoods and not distinct neighbourhoods, which are what is normally used when performing any kind of image filtering.  `A` is your image and you want to find `M x N` pixel neighbourhoods transformed as columns.  `B` would be the output where each neighbourhood is a single column and **horizontally-tiled** together.  However, you'll probably want to handle the case where you want to grab pixel neighbourhoods along the borders of the image.  In this case, you'll want to **pad** the image first.  We're going to assume that `M` and `N` are odd to allow the padding to be easier.  Specifically, you want to be sure that there are `floor(M/2)` rows padded on top of the image as well as the bottom as well as `floor(N/2)` columns padded to the left of the image as well as the right.  As such, we should pad `A` first by using [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html).  Let's assume that the border pixels will be replicated, which means that the padded rows and columns will simply be those grabbed from the top or bottom row, or the left and right column, depending on where we need to pad.  Therefore:

```
Apad = padarray(A, floor([M N]/2), 'replicate');
```

For the next part, if you want to choose specify neighbourhoods, you can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert your 2D co-ordinates into linear indices so you can select the right columns to get the right pixel blocks.  However, because you have a colour image, you'll want to perform `im2col` on each colour channel.  Unfortunately, `im2col` only works on grayscale images, and so you'd have to repeat this for each channel in your image.

As such, to get ready for patch sampling, do something like this:

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) im2col(Apad(:,:,x), [M N]), 1:size(A,3), 'uni', 0);
B = cat(3, B{:});
```

The above code will create a 3D version of `im2col`, where each 3D slice would be what `im2col` produces for each colour channel.  Now, we can use `sub2ind` to convert your `(x,y)` co-ordinates into linear indices so that we can choose which pixel neighbourhoods we want.  Therefore, assuming your positions are stored in vectors `x` and `y`, you would do something like this:

```
%// Generate linear indices
ind = sub2ind([size(A,1) size(A,2)], y, x);

%// Select neighbourhoods
%// Should be shaped as a MN x len(ind) x 3 matrix
neigh = B(:,ind,:);

%// Create cell arrays for each patch
patches = arrayfun(@(x) reshape(B(:,x,:), [M N 3]), 1:numel(ind), 'uni', 0);
```

`patches` will be a cell array where each element contains your desired patch at each location of `(x,y)` that you specify.  Therefore, `patches{1}` would be the patch located at `(x(1), y(1))`, `patches{2}` would be the patch located at `(x(2), y(2))`, etc.  For your copying and pasting pleasure, this is what we have:

```
%// Define image, M and N here
%//...
%//...

Apad = padarray(A, floor([M N]/2), 'replicate');
B = arrayfun(@(x) im2col(Apad(:,:,x), [M N]), 1:size(A,3), 'uni', 0);
B = cat(3, B{:});

ind = sub2ind([size(A,1) size(A,2)], y, x);
neigh = B(:,ind,:);
patches = arrayfun(@(x) reshape(neigh(:,x,:), [M N 3]), 1:numel(ind), 'uni', 0);
```

Comment: As I liked your approach I did a bit of testing. It seems the naive approach using `for`-loops somehow beats both our solutions!? (Using a `2000-by-2000-by-3` image and extracting more and more `3-by-3-by-3` blocks.)

Comment: @knedlsepp certain operations are faster using loops.... My guess is JIT kicked in and beat us this time!

Comment: @knedlsepp btw thanks :) also liked your approach with, `bsxfun` too.

Comment: I have to admit that I realized a few hours ago, that the `bsxfun` part doesn't actually do anything here. ;-) I guess I should delete it or actually make use of it somehow...

Answer (score 1):

As unexpected as this may seem, but for me the naive `for`-loop is actually the fastest. This might depend on your version of MATLAB though, as with newer versions they keep on improving the JIT compiler.

**Common data:**

```
A = rand(30, 30, 3); % Image
I = [5,2,3,21,24]; % I = y 
J = [3,7,5,20,22]; % J = x
s = 3; % Block size
```

### Naive approach: (faster than `im2col` and `arrayfun`!)

```
Patches = cell(size(I));
steps = -(s-1)/2:(s-1)/2;
for k = 1:numel(Patches);
    Patches{k} = A(I(k)+steps, ...
                   J(k)+steps, ...
                   :);
end
```

### Approach using `arrayfun`: (slower than the loop)

```
steps = -(s-1)/2:(s-1)/2;
Patches = arrayfun(@(ii,jj) A(ii+steps,jj+steps,:), I, J, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: @user570593: I would be interested in knowing if on your machine you get similar performance results.