# How do I write a code for a pixel wise patch extraction in a color video in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have found an explanation for pixel wise patch extraction for an image in [How do I efficiently extract image patches at specified locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733477/how-do-i-efficiently-extract-image-patches-at-specified-locations) but to implement the similar code in MATLAB for videos there are no functions available such as im2col,sub2ind etc for a color video. I would be really grateful if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I just tried the code given in  ''How do I efficiently extract image patches at specified locations?''  and similar to im2col,if there is any   function available for video the same program can be used for pixel wise patch extraction in color videos  with little changes.

Comment: I just answered this about `im2col` and color images, might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36233572/97160. Basically just call `im2col` on each color channel and stack the results in the third dimension if you want.

Comment: In my case i am working with a color video, the explanation given in stackoverflow.com/a/36233572/97160  is for a color image. I tried to modify it by adding an extra column for frames but i keep on getting the error  that the function is undefined for type uint8.

Comment: you have to process the video frame-by-frame, each frame is an image.